# Cannot find absolute path in the Mac

Tags: macos

Ok I know this is a stupid question because I have been working with Mac for years.  I have chrome installed in my applications but it doesn't show up in my terminal (not just that 98% of them).  So my first question is why they are not there? and 2 how do i get the absolute path for my chrome application?   I have right clicked the app in the finder but it just simply says Macintosh HD > Applications which to me doesn't look like a path to the app.

Sorry if this is easy to you but I am really stuck in a hole with this one.

Thank you

Dominic

ps I am using Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: `ls /Applications` is maybe what you need.

Comment: Great thanks for your advice